# Regex get all strings after first pipe

Tags: regex

I need to get strings between first pipe to third pipe.

Eg given

```
DOWN | Origin - test-pd-2 | Pool - test-pd | TCP timeout occurred
```

match:

```
Origin - test-pd-2 | Pool - test-pd
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
.*\\|(.*)\|
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel like splitting everything and then joining it, makes things easier.

Comment: Yes it should be so can you share with me the sample regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a pipe `|`, match non-pipes, pipe, non-pipes:

```
(?<=\| )[^|]+\|[^|]+[^| ]
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Nger0am6mKKgHm).

The entire match is your target

Comment: @AnılBakiDurmuş no problem. I just edited the answer to not match the spaces at either end of the match. To *include* the spaces either end use `(?<=\|)[^|]+\|[^|]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a capture group and a negated character class, you might also use

```
^[^|]*\| ([^|]+\|[^|]*[^\s|])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/27R98O/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^.+\|(.+\|{1}.+)\|.+$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GE7ALu/1/)

Note that backslashes might need to be escaped depending on the language you are using.